# Composer is running as root in docker, even though user is specified

Tags: docker, composer-php

So I have a docker-compose file:

version: '2'

```
services:
    cmd:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./cmd/Dockerfile
            context: .
            args:
                version: 7.3
        user: "1000"
        container_name: cmd
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ~/Documents/projects:/projects
            - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd
        links:
            - mysql
```

My dockerfile:

```
ARG version

FROM php:${version}-cli

# update 
RUN apt-get update

# install php extensions
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

# install composer
RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

# install laravel/lumen
RUN composer global require laravel/installer
RUN composer global require laravel/lumen-installer

# add to path
ENV PATH "$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"

# keep the container running
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

All of my composer files are under /root/ rather than $user even though I specified my user in the docker-file

Comment: Docker compose tells how to RUN the container, not how to BUILD it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user` specification in the docker-compose.yml file tells docker how to run a container based on the image, overriding any user setting inside the image.

The Dockerfile tells docker how to build the image, before you ever get to the running container stage. To change the user the image defaults to, you need to set the following inside the Dockerfile:

```
USER 1000
```

This modifies not only any container created, but also any subsequent `RUN` steps in that Dockerfile (or child images). You can also change the user multiple times within the Dockerfile if necessary.

For more details, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user